# format excel cells to stay on 1 line vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, formatting, cell

I'm trying to make cells stay with a single line formatting, I have my program autofit columns at the end so how long a text string is wouldn't be a problem, but having multiple lines for a single row is. does anybody know a way to do this without limiting string/text length?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to keep all the text in one row without wrapping, right? Then, first adjust the width and then do this in Excel's menus:

```
Format, Cell, Alignment, under Text Control, uncheck Wrap Text
```

Apply this format to all cells where you don't want wrapping. In VB, you'd use something like the following:

```
Sub FitUnWrap()
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.AutoFit
    ActiveCell.WrapText = False
End Sub
```

Replace AutoFit above with a custom value to suit your sizes. Post an example if you want more help.

Comment: ah this actually got me my answer. what i was looking for was this. wasn't sure what the call was.

        shWs.Columns.WrapText = False

     thanks!

Comment: @user3361936, I expanded my response to include VB.